# Problem with webpack not converting es6 properly

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I run `npm run build` in my directory, to get all my files bundled into bundle.js, I find this error: `ERROR in ./bundle.js from UglifyJs \n Unexpected token name «key», expected punc «;» [./bundle.js:8141,13]`.

So I went to bundle.js line 8141 and found this: `for (let key in val) {`

And therein lies the problem: `let`. Uglify cannot deal with `let` and `const`

So I've looked through the entire bundle.js file and the ONLY time let appears is literally right there, and a couple lines down, and I know specifically what package that code comes from: `npm install clone-deep`

None of the other packages I'm using are having this issue, they are all correctly converted from es6 before uglify runs, and I use let and const in my own code all the time. This one package only is causing me the issue.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "jsx2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^4.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.build.config.js"
  }
}
```

And here's my webpack.build.config.js

```
// https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'out/');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

var config = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/App.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: './bundle.js'
        //https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/593571/20785959/290f7fbc-b7b4-11e6-9ad2-7dafd7803552.png
        //https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/93
    },

    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    "presets" : ["env", "react"],
                    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

-- edit

Just to confirm, I did actually go into clone-deep index.js and change the lets to vars, and it all worked and I got no errors. I don't really consider that as a solution, because... there's no reason why this one package should have this error and nothing else. But it is definitely this one package that is the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some npm packages have no es5 version. We have to accept this or use other packages.

If you want to continue to use `clone-deep`, you have to add this package to `include` property of your `babel-loader` config:

```
...
{
    test : /\.jsx?/,
    include : [APP_DIR, path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'clone-deep')],
    loader : 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        "presets" : ["env", "react"],
        "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
    }
};
...
```

You can read more in this [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171)

Comment: Thank you my guy, brilliant. I always assumed that node modules were compiled properly by default, es6 or not.

Comment: but now I have a new question! It looks like the file is sprinkled with lost of 'const' here and there, both before and after babel handles the file. Why can babel not handle 'let' but it deal with 'const'?

Comment: before you have added `clone-deep` to the webpack config, babel didn't handle this package. All `const` and `let` had to stay in the final bundle, but it looks like `UglifyJs` can deal with `const` and `let`, but can't deal with `let` in `for` loop